# Prism Module + Entity Framework sharing one databse connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, prism

I'm currently trying to design a C# WPF App that consists of multiple modules which can be dynamically loaded (User A gets module A and B and user B gets module A and C for example).

For managing the modules, I have chosen Prism in combination with Unity.

For data persistence I would like to use the Entity Framework on which every module should take care of it by them self.

The only problem I'm facing is that this would end up with multiple database connections per user, because every module has its own connection.

So, I am searching for a way to share one database connection between the modules or is 5-10 connections no problem/normal?

Thanks.

Comment: Really? Even if it is not the same connection string? (Database name is different)

Comment: No, only connections with the same configuration can be pooled. What's the issue?

Comment: For example connection string of Module A would look like "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myModuleA;Trusted_Connection=True;" and for Module B "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myModuleB;Trusted_Connection=True;" so this ends up with 2 database connections even if it is the same server. And with 10 modules => 10 database connections. So with 10 users 100 connections. And I think this is to much.

Comment: There is nothing strange opening 10 connections to the same DB server, especially not it you are accessing 10 different databases. You may of course remove the database name from the connection string. Then the connections will be pooled.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. Everywhere you can read about "Close your database connection as soon as possible and don't forget it!" so I thought 10 connections would be a big thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modules may use a [shared service](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22907a0f-d805-4195-8272-7c284b72d2ee/example-of-using-shared-services-prism?forum=wpf) to access the database using an Entity Framework based data access layer (DAL).

The connections to the database server will be [pooled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) provided that same configuration string is used across all modules. If different users access different databases on the same server, and you want to minimize the number of connections against the server, you could omit the database name from the connection string and include it in your queries.

A relational database management system (RDBMS) such as for example SQL Server can certainly handle hundreds of simultaneous connections depending on your hardware.